# noframenumbering option with maketitle

Tags: beamer, titles, page-numbering

I would like to set the option `noframenumbering` on the title page but I don't know how to set it...

I've tried this :

```
\maketitle[noframenumbering]
```

but it didn't worked

And this :

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[noframenumbering]{
    \inserttitle
}
```

but it didn't work either...

For information this is the normal use of the `noframenumbering` option :

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering] 
    content 
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) defines `\maketitle` as a shortcut for `\titlepage` which automatically adds a `frame` environment if necessary (cf. [`beamerbasetitle.sty`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasetitle.sty), l. 21):

```
\def\maketitle{\ifbeamer@inframe\titlepage\else\frame{\titlepage}\fi}
```

So a title frame which isn't numbered can be produced by

```
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

or

```
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering] 
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
```

(You [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119920/noframenumbering-option-with-maketitle#comment267685_120016) that your title slide should be a plain frame, so I added the corresponding option in addition to `noframenumbering`.)

Answer (score 1):

If the footer in your title page is not necessary, you can add the following option to the frame:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
```

Be aware that this option hides the slide counting, but next slide will be numbered starting by 2.

Comment: My title frame is already plain. What I would like to do is to not count it in the pages numbering. For an usual frame it can be done by using the `noframenumbering` option but I don't know how to use it with the title frame.